# Place component on top of a deeply nested child in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, position, css-position

My application has the following structure (code left out for brevity):

```
<Navigation />
    <SearchMenu />
    <Tab />
        <Table />
            //some other children
                <SearchBar />
                    <PlaceHolder />
```

Due to the nature of the codebase I am working on, I need to render the `<Menu>` component as a child of `<Navigation>` and then place it right under `<SearchBar>`. I created a `<PlaceHolder>` component to easily locate its position and place the `<Menu>` on top of it. What would be the best way of achieving this?

Comment: The menu component can't be placed right under searchbar?

Comment: That's not possible, unfortunately. Like I mentioned, this is due to some technicalities with the complex codebase I am working on.

Comment: can you post a layout of how it looks now? It's really difficult to understand the question.